# How to make a random image on background

Tags: jquery, html, image

I want on my website where every 5 minutes the background changes to a new image. I want this done with jQuery if possible.

I want it to loop through 3 images. How to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInvetval(function(){
        $('body').css('background-image', 'image-path');
    }, 300000);
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear but i guess you need something like the code below, you can run it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initializing the index
    var actual = 0;

    // interval implementation
    setInterval(function(){     
 
        // setting the image
        $('body').css('background', "url('" + my_image_array[actual] + "')");
        
        // contrilling the index
        if (actual == my_image_array.length) {
          actual = 0;
        } else {
          actual = actual + 1;
        }
        
        // debugging the index
        //console.log(actual);
    }, 800); // 300000, have setted short time for tests
});

// Instantiating array
var my_image_array = new Array();

// Some images in an array structure
my_image_array[0] = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg';
my_image_array[1] = 'http://static8.depositphotos.com/1003153/893/v/950/depositphotos_8938809-Example-rubber-stamp.jpg';
my_image_array[2] = 'http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/436114/268701041/stock-vector-example-blue-square-grunge-textured-isolated-stamp-268701041.jpg';
my_image_array[3] = 'http://garsonadvogados.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/example3.jpg';
my_image_array[4] = 'http://st.depositphotos.com/1023799/2906/v/950/depositphotos_29066941-Grunge-example-rubber-stamp-vector.jpg';
```

```css
/* basic style to the body */
body{width:100%; height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the bellow script code.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var timeout = 300000;
            var i = 1;
            var action = function () {
                // Do stuff here
                if (i < 3) {
                    i++;
                } else {
                    i = 1;
                }
                console.log("image" + i);
                // $('body').css('background', "url('path/image"+i+ "')"); you can possible put your image here.
                setTimeout(action, timeout);
            };
            action();

        });
    </script>
```

In which i have create one recursive function which work infinite you can change the timeout variable what ever time you want to set. please check your browser console so you get an idea. you have to give the post fix of your image number from 1 to 3 so it will work as you want. for example image1,image2 and image3